# qsub -X non-interactively generate OpenGL plots

Tags: opengl, plot, qsub

I have an OpenGL program to generate screen plots based on data file. Since there are lots of data files need to be processed. I'm thinking use qsub with option -X (ForwardingX11), -t ( job array ). Every thing works fine at first. Each cpu will read a data file and process it. However when the code gets to the OpenGL code line.

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
```

The program breaks down and produce a qsub error file like 
    "freeglut (./video): failed to open display ''
And one more thing is, when I use echo $DISPLAY in my qsub script, it prints nothing. 
When I ssh -Y into the compute-node, I could generate OpenGL plot. So I guess the issue comes from qsub -X command. 
Does anyone have experience using qsub to generate multiple OpenGL plots?

Comment: I don't think this is likely to work unless you run the job interactively (using the -I flag).

Comment: @dbeer Right. Maybe I should find another way to do it. Thanks!